# some of my pictures are not loading on my website

Tags: html, wordpress

I was working locally, and everything was perfect. All images were loading perfectly. Once I put my website online, some of the images stopped loading, and don't appear anymore. I developped my website using wordpress 3.7.1

here is my website: http://www.ux-pm.com

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong? I have tried absolute paths and I have tried changing `<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` to other functions, but none worked.

P.S: images that are called in css are working perfectly.

Comment: Double check that your images successfully uploaded to `/wp-content/themes/uxpm/images/` as there are multiple `404` responses.

Comment: Pictures just uploaded to the hosting server? Instead, I get an error 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In site you used the images name without considering that they case sensitive, on linux server try considering case in name of file as well as in extension.

Visit http://www.ux-pm.com/wp-content/themes/uxpm/images/

You might find the difference.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. the problem is that I have used my images with uper case for first letter . thanks!

Comment: since I got the answer for this, it would be great if you answer my other question: if you open my website in firefox, you will see that my fonts are absolutely not working. I am using font-face. any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check your file names. You have named them wrongly. File names are case sensitive on linux.

You have used the name "jean.png" in your HTML but the actual file name is "Jean.png". Same is true for other missing images.

Notice the uppercase "J"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no file like that

```
http://www.ux-pm.com/wp-content/themes/uxpm/images/chapeau.png
```

so be sure that if uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site. It says the images are not in the server. Check again if the images are uploaded in the right directory. Also check if the files are uploaded properly and are of proper size.